# How do you properly use Differential Root?

Tags: differential-equations

I was trying to solve the DEQ

```
  DSolve[{-(x*y[x]) + Derivative[1][y][x] + 2*x*(2 + x)*Derivative[2][y][x] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

The result returns a [*Differential Root*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRoot.html).

I looked at the documentation, tried getting the function, tried converting the solution to a function, tried putting in values to get numerical results, but nothing seems to work.

How are you supposed to properly use Differential Root?

Note: I know how to do numerical results, but I had not seen this Differential Root before and the examples are interesting, so would like to understand how to use this holonomic function better.

Maybe it is the case that it just cannot validly do anything with it for some mathematical reason.

Comment: `tried putting in values to get numerical results, but nothing seems to work.` there are unknown constants of integrations in there,  But basically when `DSolve` returns `DifferentialRoot` it means it could not solve it analytically. This is very similar to Maple's `DESol`. Try with initial conditions, and if you get `DifferentialRoot` again, try now to plot it as was done in the example in the link you showed. `DifferentialRoot` to an ODE is kinda like `Root` object to `Solve`.

Comment: @Nasser: If you put in ICs, why not just use numerical methods? In other words, why have this result at all?

Comment: It is an exact expression, that can be treated like other exact expressions, within limits. What is `Sin[x]` other than a link to algorithms that perform symbolic and numerical computations? Like some other esoteric special functions, there are limitations to what can be calculated from a `DifferentialRoot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = -(x*y[x]) + Derivative[1][y][x] + 2*x*(2 + x)*Derivative[2][y][x] == 0;

sol[c1_, c2_] = DSolve[eqn, y, x][[1]] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
```

[image]

To get a numeric value, `c1`,  `c2`, and `x` must have numeric values.

```
y[1.] /. sol[1, 1]

(* 1. *)
```

However, inexact values for the arbitrary constants fail

```
y[1.] /. sol[1.1, 1.2]
```

[image]

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the arbitrary constants

```
y[1.] /. sol @@ Rationalize[{1.1, 1.2}]

(* 1.1 *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[
   Evaluate[y[x] /. (sol @@ Rationalize[{c1, c2}])], {x, 0, 2},
   PlotRange -> {-3.5, 4}] // Quiet,
 {{c1, 1}, -2, 2, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c2, 1}, -2, 2, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]