# DSolve doesn't output a solution

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a second-order linear ODE, here is my input

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

DSolve[{(4 r^3 + B^2 r - 4 r b1 + 4 b1 - 2 B b1 - (B
          ^2)/2 + 4) f[r] + 2 (r^2 - Br/2 + b1)^2  f''[r] + 2 f'[r] - 
    2 == 0}, f[r], r]
```

and I got
[image]
which exactly not a solution. Did I miss something?

Comment: are you sure you meant `Br/2` and not `B*r/2`? This looks like a typo to me. But there is no solution either way. I just wanted to point this out just in case.

Comment: @Nasser You are right, it's a typo, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a good explanation for what you are asking here:
[How do you properly use Differential Root?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226145/how-do-you-properly-use-differential-root)

I know this is not an answer, but my reputation is not enough for commenting on your post.
Hope it helps!